# Transitivity of containment of angles.

Tags: geometry, angle, axiomatic-geometry

Suppose the ray AD is in the interior of
the $\angle BAC$, and the ray AE is in
the interior of the $ \angle DAC$. Show
that AE is also in the interior of $ \angle BAC$. Using Hilbert's axioms this is [exercise 9.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=C5fSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96) in Hartshorne's book Geometry: Euclid and Beyond pg 96.

I have alot of trouble with proving rigorously really obvious things in mathematics i imagine this exercise isn't meant to be that difficult but i cant seem to figure out where to start.

[image: Angles]

Comment: I think you mean "in the interior of the $\angle DAC"$ , not $"\angle DAG"$.

Comment: You should start by writing down the precise definition of "in the interior of."

Comment: Its actually not very clear what the interior is but basically its between the two lines AB and CA i think i actually got the question i just haven't had time to write out the solution here. a sketch of the idea is to draw a line from B to C then use that the ray AE is interior to angle DAC so you can find a point on that line call it F then you can do the same for the larger angle call it H. we have H is on the line BC and F is on the line HC so by I1 we have F is on the line BC so F is interior of the largest angle.

Comment: The idea seems okay, but I'm not too sure about the order in which you built your points. I'd rather go for $H$ first then $F$. Also, the notion of interior was precisely defined earlier in chapter 7, although the link you provided doesn't seem to have the related definition in the free excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notions from chapter 7 "Axioms of betweenness" of the book would be helpful here.
From the same pdf I linked in one of your earlier previous question, you have the definition:

> The *inside* (or *interior*) of an angle $\angle BAC$ consists of all points
>   $D$ such that $D$ and $C$ are on the same side of the line $AB$, and $B$ and $B$ are on the same side of the line $AC$.

Note that earlier in the chapter they properly define what it means to be "on the same side" of a line.
Using Proposition 7.3 (Crossbar theorem) that comes right after the passage I quoted, you should be able to prove that:

> A ray $AD$ is inside the angle $\angle BAC$ if and only if ray $AD$ meets segment $BC$.

The crossbar theorem gives you one implication.
Conversely suppose 
$\angle BAC$ is an angle and there is some point $D'$ on ray $AD$ such that
$B\ast D'\ast C$.
Then $D'$ and $C$ are on the same side of line $AB$.
Because line $AB$ intersects line $AD$ at point $A$, it splits line $AD$ into two rays, one on either side of line $AB$. One of these rays is precisely ray $AD$. That ray $AD$ contains $D'$ by assumption, so $D$ and $D'$ are on the same side of line $AB$, it follows that $D$ and $C$ are on the same side of line $AB$. Similarly, $D$ and $B$ are on the same side of line $AC$. Therefore, ray $AD$ is inside angle $\angle BAC$.

I think the above proof holds with your axioms. I didn't read chapter 7 in detail but it contains stuff about "plane separation" (by a line) and "line separation" (by a point), so I assume most of the intuition about "betweenness" should be available when they define the interior of an angle.

---

From there a possible proof for your exercise would be to use the crossbar theorem twice:

- find $D'$ on ray $AD$ and segment $BC$ (the point you called $H$ in the comments)
- then you can get a point $E'$ on ray $AE$ and segment $D'C$ (the point you called $F$)

Then you have $B\ast D'\ast C$ and $D'\ast E'\ast C$, from which you should be able to deduce $B\ast E'\ast C$ from some result in the book. At least I hope something like that is in there.
You can conclude with the characterization of a ray inside an angle that I gave above.

---

Is there something simpler/faster? Maybe, I haven't checked everything in the book. Maybe there's a result related to my characterization of a ray inside an angle somewhere in the book that you can re-use to go faster. One suspicious place would be the exercises in chapter 7 (that I didn't check out).

Comment: You know that the ray AE' is interior to the angle BAC after using the crossbar theorem but the ray AE'= the ray AE so the ray AE is interior to angle BAC as desired immediately.